# xpath. the correct xpath notation.

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

i am building a webscraper to get the information of a webpage. i want the correct xpath notation to get the information .

```
<div class="inner">
<div class="col">
  <h2><a href="land-in-kadawatha-for-sale-gampaha-442">Land in Kadawatha</a></h2>
  <div class="meta">
      <div class="date"></div>
      <span class="category">Other Lands</span>,
    <span class="location">Gampaha</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

how do i access the "Land in Kadawatha" using a xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this function:

```
<xsl:function name="markup:has-class" as="xs:boolean">
   <xsl:param name="el" as="element()" />
   <xsl:param name="class-name" as="item()" />

   <xsl:sequence select="$el/@class and tokenize(upper-case(normalize-space($el/@class)), ' ') = upper-case(string($class-name))" />
</xsl:function>
```

You can do:

```
*[markup:has-class(., 'inner')]/*[markup:has-class(., 'col')]//h2/string()
```

Adjust accordingly depending on your context node.

Answer (score 2):

Standalone XPath 1 without xsl:

```
//div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " inner ")]/div[contains(concat(" ", @class, " "), " col ")]/h2[1]/a
```

Comment: What's all the complexity for? What's wrong with `[@class="inner"]`, or if you want to be safe, `[normalize-space(@class)="inner"]`?

Comment: Too make it more reliable. They could add new classes, then the class could be `foo inner bar`

Answer (score 0):

Based on that snippet

```
//div[@class='col']/h2/a
```

then your code would look like

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='col']/h2/a"));
string elementText = element.Text();
```